# Complex MySQL count using a join

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, what's happening is there is a table which tracks checkins to businesses(BID) by username(UID). $startday = beginning of the day

```
Checkins:
 ID | UID | BID | DATE
```

Then there is a second table which tracks friends. User can be a SENDER or RECIEVER

```
Friends:
 SENDER | RECIEVER | STATUS
```

What I'm trying to do is count the number of checkins from any friends. So (pseudocode)

```
(if(SENDER = UID) AND (RECEIVER exists in checkins) AND (DATE > $startday)) OR
(if(RECEIVER = UID) AND (SENDER exists in checkins) AND (DATE > $startday))
```

Then count those results. I know I'll need to do a JOIN of some kind, but I really don't know where to start with this design. I'd appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Checkins ch
JOIN Friends fr
ON (fr.SENDER = ch.UID OR fr.RECIEVER = ch.UID)
WHERE ch.DATE = '$startday'
```

Comment: I was able to get this one working. I had to add ` AND ch.bid = '$bid' AND ch.uid <> '$uid'` to get it going correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** This is not pretty at all and can probably be done a lot neater, I make no claims to its performance, simply trying to give you a starting point, presuming I understand the question correctly.

**Assumptions:** I have assumed the following:

- Friends are defined by being in ANY relationship either SENDER or RECEIVER
- You want a count for a single individual of how many of their friends in total have checked in
- That you can add your own WHERE clause to dictate the date ranges to check

**Answer:** The below query worked for me

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM checkins
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT friend FROM 
    (
        SELECT receiver AS friend FROM Friends
            WHERE sender = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sender AS friend FROM Friends
            WHERE receiver = 1
    ) AS t 
) AS allfriends
    ON checkins.uid = allfriends.friend
```

**Example Data:** I used is as follows

Checkins

```
ID          UID         BID         Date
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
1           1           1           NULL
2           2           1           NULL
3           3           1           NULL
4           4           1           NULL
5           5           1           NULL
6           6           1           NULL
7           1           1           NULL
8           2           1           NULL
9           3           1           NULL
10          4           1           NULL
```

Friends

```
sender      receiver    status
----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           NULL
1           3           NULL
1           4           NULL
2           3           NULL
2           5           NULL
2           6           NULL
3           1           NULL
2           1           NULL
```

**Explanation:** I'll break it up so you can understand it easily (you can run each of these individually to see the results).

First I got a list of all the IDs of a users friends where they are the sender (for UID 1).

```
        SELECT receiver AS friend FROM Friends
            WHERE sender = 1
```

Result:

```
friend
-----------
2
3
4
```

Then again where they're the receiver.

```
        SELECT sender AS friend FROM Friends
            WHERE receiver = 1
```

Result:

```
friend
-----------
3
2
```

Then `UNION ALL` them together to get a list containing duplicates.

```
        SELECT receiver AS friend FROM Friends
            WHERE sender = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sender AS friend FROM Friends
            WHERE receiver = 1
```

Result:

```
friend
-----------
2
3
4
3
2
```

Removed the duplicates doing a `DISTINCT` subselect

```
    SELECT DISTINCT friend FROM 
    (
        SELECT receiver AS friend FROM Friends
            WHERE sender = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sender AS friend FROM Friends
            WHERE receiver = 1
    ) AS t
```

Result:

```
friend
-----------
2
3
4
```

Finally I joined the checkins table to the list of distinct friends, based on the userid using an `INNER JOIN`. `INNER JOIN` will pull all results from `checkins` where the `uid` also exists in our subselect `allfriends`. Adding COUNT(*) gives you a count of all the rows.

Result of full query:

```
6
```

You can then wrap your date selection around this, using a `WHERE`, to only get the results `BETWEEN` two dates as required.